# Makefile:85: recipe for target 'obj/gemm.o' failed

Tags: makefile, data-annotations, image-segmentation, yolo, darknet

I'm trying to train my own dataset annotated using segmentation so i downloaded yolo segmentation project in github , and i tried to compile the project using this command " make -j6 " ( i followed instruction ) 
I get some errors when i compile , i tell the owner of this tool about compilation problems , so he tell me that that the tool have some problem on windows but it works on linux , So i ask about who get those errors maybe it can help me to resolve those problems

Repository that i used :

> https://github.com/ArtyZe/yolo_segmentation

[image: a compilation errors]

Thanks

Updating : 
I have copied 3rd party folder from AlexayAB and i modify the Makefile file 
from :

```
COMMON= -Iinclude/ -Isrc/
```

to this :

```
COMMON= -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -I3rdparty/stb/include
```

And when i compile i get this : (the error of pthread doesn't appear again )

[image: Errors that i get]

Answer (score 1):

`pthread` is unix utility so it won't work directly on windows. Plus I don't think that repo will work on windows. So to be able to run darknet on windows you will need to include 3rd party library such as `pthread.h`. You can copy the `pthread.h` header file from this repo : https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/3rdparty/pthreads/include/pthread.h

If you want to run darknet on windows I suggest you search for repo that support windows build such as Alexey's repo : https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet

Comment: I have darknet and i have copied 3rd party library folder to yolo segmentation repository but it doesn't work

Comment: of course it won't work. Linking header file is not as simple as that. It's the same as you have to make program that originally made to run on Linux also run on Windows. For example if you are using Visual Studio you have to manage the Linker dependency, etc. That's why instead of creating darknet window version by yourself, why don't you fork another repo that support Windows build? It will be much simpler.

Comment: I can't really read the language, also the `pthreads.h` is not in `stb/include` , it's in `3rdparty/pthreads/include`

Comment: Yes i know but the error it disappear after changing the line of code and copying the folder of 3rdparty , for now i get this two errors and i hope they will be resolved